# Could one see his hands in a dark moonless night in Sahara desert?

Tags: experimental-physics

If you were standing in a place on earth on a moonless night where there was no other light to be seen except starlight, could you see your hand held in front of your eyes?

Comment: Yes. Yes you can. No personal data for the Sahara (why all the capital letters), but plenty of new-moon nights up in the Rocky Mountains of the US with stars galore.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely that you will see it, especially after your eyes are adapted to darkness. However, the main reason seems to be not the light from the stars but other sources. See here, for example:
http://www.skyandtelescope.com/astronomy-blogs/why-we-can-see-in-the-dark/